# Deleting Non-empty Directory with smbclient

Tags: linux, shell, shell-script, samba

How can I remove a non-empty directory with smbclient?
I have tried the following:

1) `rm`

Result:

```
NT_STATUS_NO_SUCH_FILE listing [dir_path]
```

2) `recurse;rm`

Result:

```
No Error but also nothing happens! The folder remains as before!
```

3) `rmdir`

Result:

```
NT_STATUS_DIRECTORY_NOT_EMPTY removing remote directory file [dir_path]
```

4) `recurse;rmdir`

Result:

```
NT_STATUS_DIRECTORY_NOT_EMPTY removing remote directory file [dir_path]
```

5) `rm [dir_name]/*;rmdir [dir_name]`

Result:

```
NT_STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND deleting remote file [sub_dir_path]

NT_STATUS_DIRECTORY_NOT_EMPTY removing remote directory file [dir_path]
```

6) `recurse;rm [dir_name]/*;rmdir [dir_name]`

Result:

```
NT_STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND deleting remote file [sub_dir_path]

NT_STATUS_DIRECTORY_NOT_EMPTY removing remote directory file [dir_path]
```

Comment: 1) rm 2) recurse;rm 3) rmdir 4) recurse;rmdir 5) rm dirname/*;rmdir

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show exactly what you tried, and the errors you got (if any). Don't put that information in comments please.

Comment: OK, I found a workaround: Mounting the remote windows share folder to a local directory and then doing "rm -r"
Thanks to Mikhail who gave the hint [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15025373/deleting-non-empty-directory-with-smbclient)

Comment: This question was on stackoverflow, and the interesting answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/15025524/2996931

Answer (score 6):

A little late, but since 4.7.0 version of smbclient there is a deltree command that is able to do that. It will delete all files and directories matching mask from the current working directory on the server. 
No need to turn recurse on

```
smb: \> deltree <mask>
```

Comment: You should elaborate your answer. As it is now, it's more of a comment.

Comment: Agreed with the above comment, although a quick search indicates that `deltree` was added *to smbclient*.

Answer (score 2):

You can write some lines:

```
myHost=fubar
myShare=batch
myRootPath="next_version\\SNAPSHOT"
myDirectory="snafu-fubar"
myCredentials="sbb.ch\\ricky%password"                                                                                                                               

smbclient \\\\${myHost}\\${myShare} -D "${myRootPath}" -U ${myCredentials} -c "recurse on; ls ${myDirectory}" | grep '^\\' \
   | awk -F\\ '{print NF,$0}' | sort -nr | cut -d ' ' -f2- \
   | while read -r myDir; do
      myRoot="${myDir%\\*}"
      myFolder="${myDir##*\\}"
      smbclient \\\\${myHost}\\${myShare} -D "${myDir}" -U ${myCredentials} -c "del *" || true
      smbclient \\\\${myHost}\\${myShare} -D "${myRoot}" -U ${myCredentials} -c "rmdir \"${myFolder}\"" || true
done
```

Answer (score 0):

From OP's comment:

> OK, I found a workaround: Mounting the remote windows share folder to a local directory and then doing "rm -r" Thanks to Mikhail who gave the hint [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15025373) – rahimi 2 days ago

With this, the question is effectively answered (and, as a side-effect, removed from Unanswered Questions queue).

Comment: -1, This is a non-answer to the real question, how do you do this with smbclient?

Comment: If you know the answer chief, by all means.

Comment: It is not possible, that is the answer.  The `smbclient` tool is poorly designed and definitely can not do that... save some time at least.  In many cases mounting a samba share is not a practical solution, so there is a huge incentive to know whether `smbclient` can do this thing.